# how to make new line in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I search for some code, even I found it, but I dunno how to add a new line of the javascript he creates.
The original link is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqetf/), I have some problem in code bellow. Because I have change the code `"price": "120.00",` to `"price": "\\using php to call some data",`.

This is original code:

```
{
    "product_id": "1",
        "store_id": "1",
        "price": "120.00",
        "sequence": "0",
        "id": "1",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "name": "Store 1",
        "email": "store1@store1.com"
}
```

This is what I wrote:

```
$result1=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from product"); 
while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
   $pno1 = $row1["no"];
   $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM xx where WHERE product_id = '$pno1') ";
   $query1 = mysqli_query($conn , $sql1);
   $rowcont1 = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
 ?>
   {
      "name": "<?php echo $row1["PACKAGE_NAME"]; ?>",
      "id": "<?php echo $row1["PACKAGE_NAME"]; ?>",
      "cat": "UNIFI",
      <?php
            if ($rowcont1 == 0)
            {
                ?>
                    "vas": "<?php echo "No default vas"; ?>" 
                <?php
            }
            else 
            {
                ?>
                    "vas": "<?php
                    while($rowvas1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
                    {
                        echo "$rowvas1[PACKAGE_NAME]\\n\\n"; //This is the line I want to chage (\\n no function for me)
                    }
                    ?>"
                <?php
            } 
            ?> 
     },
    <?php
```

I have found many question same with me, but even I have tried all of the solutions, my code still didn't work

Comment: str.replace('\n', '<br/>');

Comment: tried, and still same. Thankyou for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
echo "$rowvas1[PACKAGE_NAME]<br>";
```

Instead of `\n` just add html line-break `<br>`.

**Edit:** If you are using the JS provided in the `jsfiddle`, be sure to change the following line:

```
$('#price-store').text(pricestore[$('option:selected', this).index()].price);
```

to(`.text(` to `.html(`):

```
$('#price-store').html(pricestore[$('option:selected', this).index()].price);
```